# How do I create a toString using another 'helper' class in my Tree java?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, linked-list

I'm trying to figure out how to create a toString() method from the parentheticRepresentation class given below.

```
public static <E> String parentheticRepresentation(Tree<E> T, Position<E> v) {
        String s = v.element().toString();
        if (T.islnternal(v)) {
        Boolean firstTime = true;
        for (Position<E> w : T.children(v))
        if (firstTime) {
        s += " ( " + parentheticRepresentation(T, w);

        firstTime = false;
        }
        else s += ", " + parentheticRepresentation(T, w);
        s += " ) ";
        }
        return s;
        }
```

In my main class, when I create the nodes for my tree, and try to output the whole Tree, it just outputs one Node with parentheticRepresenation. So how do I create another toString() class using this so that when I call to output my tree, it gives me the representation as in the class above. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedTree<Character> T = new LinkedTree();

    // add root
    T.addRoot('A');

    // add children of root
    T.createNode('B', (TreeNode) (T.root()), new NodePositionList());
    TreePosition C = T.createNode('C', (TreeNode) (T.root()),
            new NodePositionList());
    T.createNode('D', (TreeNode) (T.root()), new NodePositionList());

    // add children of node C

    T.createNode('E', C, new NodePositionList());
    TreePosition F = T.createNode('F', C, new NodePositionList());
    T.createNode('G', C, new NodePositionList());

    // add childrn of Node F
    T.createNode('H', F, new NodePositionList());
    T.createNode('I', F, new NodePositionList());

    // print out tree

    System.out.println("Size = " + T.size());
    System.out.println("Here is the tree:");
    System.out.println(T);

}
```

}

Comment: Are you expecting something like A(B,C(E,F(H,I),G),D)?

Comment: yes. i just cant figure out what to write in my toString method that returns me that output using parentheticRepresentation.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a pre-order traversal, just opening parenthesis when you traverse the children and then closing it afterwards.

Something like this (not sure if it works since i didnt test it, but just to give you an idea).

```
public static <E> String parentheticRepresentation(Tree<E> T, Position<E> v) {
    String s = "";
    if (T.islnternal(v)) {
        s = v.element().toString(); //adds node to string      
        if(T.children(v).size() > 0)
        {
            s += "("; //opens parenthesis for children
            for (Position<E> w : T.children(v))
            {
                s += parentheticRepresentation(T, w) + ",";
            }
            s = s.deleteCharAt(s.length() - 1); //deletes last comma
            s += ")"; //closes parenthesis for children
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

To override toString() method, add something like this to the Tree class.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
     //Just speculating the TreeHelper name, but its calling the helper method.
     return TreeHelper.parentheticRepresentation(this,this.root());
}
```

edit: using "this" reference since we are inside the Tree class.

Comment: Okay I understand that, but how do I create a toString() method that returns me that parentheticRepresentation

Comment: you would need to override the toString() method on the Tree class, and call this method on it.

Comment: @Override
 public String toString() {
  Tree<E> T = null;
  Position<E> v = null;
  return parentheticRepresentation(T, v);
  
 }

Comment: I tried doing this but its giving me errors upon compilation

Comment: I tried using your edit as well, but that only outputs the node "A", i.e. the root.

Comment: I have included the rest of the code in my edit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's obvious that the OP is in my data structures class....

Here's what I have done (with the bracket representation method given to us).

```
private static <E> String parentheticRepresentation (Tree <E> T, Position <E> v){

    String s = v.element().toString();

    if (T.isInternal(v)){

        Boolean firstTime = true;


        Iterator <Position<E>> it = T.children(v).iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()){

            Position<E> w = it.next();


            if (firstTime) {

                s+= " ( " + parentheticRepresentation (T,w);
                firstTime = false;
            }

            else s+= ", " + parentheticRepresentation (T,w);
        s+= " )";
    }}

    return s;

            }



public String toString() 
{
return parentheticRepresentation(this,this.root());

}
```

The problem is that I keep getting stack overflow errors for my child methods (which are added below)

EDIT: I fixed the stack overflow errors but know I have the same problem as the OP. Only the root (A) is outputted.

```
public Position<E> parent(Position<E> v) throws InvalidPositionException,
        BoundaryViolationException {
    TreePosition<E> p = checkPosition(v);
    Position<E> parentPosition = p.getParent();
    if (parentPosition == null)
        throw new BoundaryViolationException("No parent");
    return parentPosition;
}

public Iterable<Position<E>> children(Position<E> v)
        throws InvalidPositionException {
    TreePosition <E> p = checkPosition(v);

    if (isExternal(v))    //STACK OVERFLOW
        throw new InvalidPositionException("");
return p.getChildren();
}

public boolean isInternal(Position<E> v) throws InvalidPositionException {

    checkPosition(v);
    return (children(v) != null);

}

public boolean isExternal(Position<E> v) throws InvalidPositionException {
    checkPosition(v);  
    return (children(v) == null); // STACK OVERFLOW
}
```

Comment: yup getting the same thing... 'A'.